how to assert total number of items on 50 pages where each page has 10 items in cypress?
The url does not have a pagenumber param. There is a next button and value for each page. There is no length. Each page has a value that says 10. I need to assert and get the total value to be equal to given value.
The elements are like this for the 'NEXT':
 Next > 
The elements are like this for the 'ul':
class="usa-pagination__list js-pager__items"
The elements are like this for the 'page 1':
1
I need to use cypress with javascript here.
Tired below:
describe.only('Count of Total', () => {
it('Total count of items', () => { 
    cy.visit('/');
    let totalItemsCount =0;

    function countItemsOnPage() {
        cy.get('a.usa-pagination__button')
            .then($anchors => {
                totalItemsCount+=$anchors.length;
                cy.get('.usa-pagination__link-text') 
                    .then($linkText =>{
                        if($linkText.is(':enabled')) {
                            cy.wrap($linkText).click();
                            cy.wait(500);
                            countItemsOnPage();
                        } else {
                            cy.log('${totalItemsCount}');
                        }
                    })
    })
}
countItemsOnPage();

})
})

It sounds like you are asking how to handle pagination, but we cannot really tell since the question is rather messy. Please be more specific about what you want to do.

The question is simple: How would you validate that there are 568 items in the list?

Yes, I assumed that, but I was asking for a cleanup of the question to make it more readable.

WRT to the implementation, why don't you just click the next button say 56 times (568/10) then count the last page?

the code is like this:

Movies


TV Shows


Morning Shows


Moonlight


Music



@E.Swallow can you please tell me how to count when the code is like below?
10
25
50
100
- All -


You've set up your test fixture/conditions so that you have 568 items on various pages. There are 10 items per page, and there's a "Next Page" button to click that takes you to the next page.
The way to write this test is something like this:
cy.visit('my-page')

// assert there are 56 pages of 10 items each
Cypress._.times(56, () => {
  cy.get('a.usa-pagination__button').should('have.length', 10)
  cy.get('.usa-pagination__link-text').click()  // next page
})

// assert the last page has 8 items
cy.get('a.usa-pagination__button').should('have.length', 8)

// assert there are no more pages
cy.get('.usa-pagination__link-text').should('be.disabled')

It's pretty straight forward once you grasp the basic testing concept of setting up the test conditions. You can do that with a cy.intercept() command and using a fixture.
The other thing you should do at each page is check the page number or something that indicates the new page has loaded (maybe check the first link content).
